# Ensuring if excel worksheet contains any user defined function

Tags: java, excel

My application contains an upload option from which the user can upload files(any file). 
I know that users have the ability to write code/scripts in excel worksheet.So how can i prevent that from happening as it can lead to security breach.
Or what check can i apply to know that the uploaded worksheet contains any function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from the Java tag that your appliction to which the sheet gets uploaded is a Java application.

Using `Apache POI`, you can use a `POIFSReader` (see this [doc](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/how-to.html)) to read the file on a lower level.

There is an [example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-if-xls-excel-file-contains-a-macro.html) by Réal Gagnon which shows how you can check the content by looking at the name.

I had to modify the listener (added another comparision)

```
class MacroListener implements POIFSReaderListener {
  [...]

  @Override
  public void processPOIFSReaderEvent(POIFSReaderEvent event) {
    System.out.println("  Event: Name " + event.getName() + ", path "
            + event.getPath());
    if (event.getPath().toString().startsWith("\\Macros")
            || event.getPath().toString().startsWith("\\_VBA")
            || event.getPath().toString().contains("_VBA_")) {
        this.macroDetected = true;
    }
  }
}
```

so that it worked for some test files. You might have to tune/extend the checks.

Comment: `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA` is for simple cell formulas.  The OP wants to know how to detect Macros.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Thanks for the hint, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Solved my purpose. :)

Comment: @Prerit You're welcome. Thank you for confirming that it solved your problem.